# Connecting with TFS using HTTP Rest client Java on windows

Tags: java, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to access work item from TFS through Http Client, in response I am getting the HTML of the sign in page.

In authentication header i am passing PAT string. Also tried using TFSTeamProjectCollection from TFS-SDK (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22616) but result is same.

Is there any API for JAVA that helps in getting response from TFS.

Answer (score 2):

There is the samples in [TFS JAVA SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases) package (e.g. TFS-SDK-14.120.0.zip).

Simple code:

```
URI serverURI=null;
            try {

                serverURI = new URI("[collection url");
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Credentials credentials=new UsernamePasswordCredentials("XXX","XXX");
            TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TFSTeamProjectCollection(serverURI, credentials);
                    tpc.authenticate();
WorkItemClient workItemClient = tpc.getWorkItemClient(); 
WorkItem wi=workItemClient.getWorkItemByID(8);
```

Simple steps to configure project to use TFS JAVA SDK:

1. Right click your project in Eclipse> Properties
2. Select Java build Path
3. Select Libraries tab
4. Click Add JARs> Choose sdk jar file (It is in [sdk folder]\redist\lib folder)
5. Expand the added jar
6. Select Native library location> Edit
7. Choose the folder that in [SDK folder]\redist/native/… per to windows operation system. (e.g. [SDK folder]\redist/native/win32/x86_64 for windows 64 bit OS)

Comment: can I download a project using this SDK? I did not find any docs about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A [**REST client**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/rest-clients) simplifies calling [Visual Studio Team Services REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) from your client-side (JavaScript/TypeScript) extension code.

If you want a Java API, use the SDK. There is a Team Services SDK for Java, you could download it from GitHub as a part of team-explorer-everywhere.

The download link from GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases