# Issue with connecting tfs using java tfs sdk programatically

Tags: java, tfs, sdk

I have code where i'm connecting to TFS using java tfs sdk like below,

*

```
*Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials( "xxxxxx", "XXXXX"); getConnection(serverURI, credentials, maxDate, buildNo);
 } 
private static void getConnection(URI serverURI, final Credentials credentials, String maxDate, String buildNo) 
{ 
TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = null;
 try{ 
tpc = new TFSTeamProjectCollection(serverURI, credentials); 
tpc.authenticate();
 }catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
}*
```

- 

But its stop authenticating using username and password, what the alternative authentication type like PAT - i need code to authenticate it, please help on this.

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Hi Tried the above code what you mentioned but I'm getting issue below,

Looks like no java code to connect TFS using PAT in JAVA TFS SDK?.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.platformmisc.NativePlatformMisc.nativeGetEnvironmentVariable(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; at com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.platformmisc.NativePlatformMisc.nativeGetEnvironmentTFSTestConnection.getConnection(TFSTestConnection.java:68) at TFSConnection - httpClientReference is null

Comment: Hi Tried the above code what I mentioned but I'm getting issue below,

Looks like no java code to connect TFS using PAT in JAVA TFS SDK?.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with username and password as credentials, and I can connect to TFS normally on my side.

[image]

Here is a [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45408588/11508192) you can refer to .